# How to implement linebreak with trailling dots using UITextView Swift

Tags: ios, swift3, uikit, uitextview

How to implement line-break with trailing dots using UITextView Swift.
TextView Size => Width - 200, Height - 50

```
textView.textContainer.maximumNumberOfLines = 0
textView.textContainer.lineBreakMode = .byTruncatingTail
textView.textContainer.lineFragmentPadding = 0
```

I have used above line of code to implement the same.

(Note : There is 5 blank lines in between line1 and Line2)
Sample Text :

TestLine1

TestLine2 
TestLine3

Expected output. TestLine1...

And on clicking display the complete code.

Please suggest. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Whatever you'r doing is done on UITextField not on UITextView so first confirm on what functionality what wanted to implement.

Comment: @dahiya_boy : I am using UITextView not the UITextField. The functionality is simple if we have TextView like : Width - 200, Height - 50 and the text like below. 

Line1 




Line2Line2Line2Line2Line2Line2Line2Line2Line2

Line3Line3Line3Line3Line3Line3Line3Line3Line3.

So it should show the text Line1... something like this

Comment: TextView have scrollview so you never truncate it, Eg. when you write whats app message have ever your message is truncated? check it out. bro

Comment: @dahiya_boy : Yes your correct but as I have use like that because on clicking the TextView will expend it in full size text. Actually we have to implement the component which supports links and byTruncatingTail. I think you got my point.

Comment: Set frame of textView as per requirement. When where clicked on it change its size as per its content. Still you can not truncate as per my knowledge.

Comment: @dahiya_boy : Yes your right I think so UITextView is not supporting truncate. I have implemented the expanding UITextView. 

Thank you very much.